# forms.DateInput default value

Tags: javascript, django

I am using  a calendar widget using django forms, part of the code-

```
class DateForm(forms.ModelForm):
   helper.layout = Layout(
      Div(
            Field('start', placeholder='date')
       )

    class Meta:
       model = Date
       widgets = {
           'start': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
       }
```

How can I add a default value of todays date to the 'start' variable? I cannot seem to find any default for dateinput. Very new to Django and javascript- thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
'start': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'})
```

to

```
'start': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker', 'value': datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")})
```

This will set a default value for the date input field. You can change the date format as per the format you want to set.